# Is there a convention for multi port cuse driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, fuse

I wonder is there a convention for multiple port cuse drivers. [Given cuse example](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/cuse_8c.html) takes a device name and opens a port for just that given port. What if I want to open 4 ports for example, what am I supposed to do? Should I run multiple processes for each port or should I fork...?

If I prefer to implement kernel space version, generally an index table is used. However, for cuse, I couldn't find an example such kind.